# javascript onclick not working on a P element

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've copied code from another page in my site that launches a video in a pop up window, but for some reason the code does not bring up the video on the new page.

However, I've taken the exact same code (except I cannot apply it to a DIV this time) and applied it to the P element, but it does not launch the video.

Here's my code:

```
    <p onclick="javascript:launchActivity('C191D24F-9B1A-FB59-C4EE7E3257C019F4','video')" style="cursor:pointer;"><img class="top" src="/resource/uploads/left-navs/blue-camera.png" />
                <a href="#">some text</a></p>
```

and I've taken it from the WORKING code:

```
    <div onclick="javascript:launchActivity('C191D24F-9B1A-FB59-C4EE7E3257C019F4','video')" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block; margin-top:10px;">
        <a href="#"><i>vid text launch<img border="0" src="/resource/uploads/PrebuildSNLO/text_arrow.png" style="padding-left: 3px;" /></a></div>
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: And you copied over the `launchActivity` too right ;)

Comment: just out of interest, who is it going round teaching all these people to use inline javascript events? Is there a root person that I could have taken care of that would filter down to the rest?

Comment: Get rid of `javascript:` it is useless there.

Comment: You may need to set the `p` element's `display:inline-block;` or perhaps `display:block;`.

Comment: No, he didn't make a copy of the div he's trying to open as a modal. See my answer, below.

Comment: @musefan: "Unobtrusive JavaScript" right? Not saying it's right for all cases, but it's a useful, simple approach, and in some cases, can be extremely beneficial... like when you want to guarantee no latency between the element's behavior being available and the DOM being loaded. Let's not be too hasty to throw out our tools.

Comment: and there are many cooks in the kitchen so to speak to answer musefan's question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The launchActivity function is using jQuery to search for an element on the page, which doesn't exist. There is an element on the old page with this id

```
C191D24F-9B1A-FB59-C4EE7E3257C019F4
```

I assume this is the video, so it will need copying to the new page.

```
<div class="videoPlayer" id="C191D24F-9B1A-FB59-C4EE7E3257C019F4" title="SN1 Common Core" video="http://d1by67ljd45m4v.cloudfront.net/media/C1920522-F3C9-DB50-3F3D3CC1CACC01B7.mov" videoendredirect="">
    <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        <div style="background-color:white;">
            <strong>Problem loading video..</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this too but it looks like a div (with no ID but with a set of classes) is being added to the body of the page. Not sure where it's going wrong as the `launchActivity` method just seems to fail quietly without throwing any errors...

Comment: yes that solved the issue. Very novice with JavaScript so thanks indeeed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you didn't copy this into your new page, from the original page:

```
<div videoendredirect="" video="http://d1by67ljd45m4v.cloudfront.net/media/C1920522-F3C9-DB50-3F3D3CC1CACC01B7.mov" id="C191D24F-9B1A-FB59-C4EE7E3257C019F4" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable videoPlayer" style="display: none; width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 491.267px; visibility: hidden;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" title="SN1 Common Core">
    <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        <div style="background-color:white;">
            <strong>Problem loading video..</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script you're trying to call is looking for an object with the ID of C191D24F-9B1A-FB59-C4EE7E3257C019F4. When it can't find it, it fails.